# How to set SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS parameter using spark-env.sh file

Tags: apache-spark, sparklyr

I am trying to change the location spark writes temporary files to. Everything I've found online says to set this by setting the `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` parameter in the `spark-env.sh` file, but I am not having any luck with the changes actually taking effect.

Here is what I've done:

1. Created a 2-worker test cluster using Amazon EC2 instances. I'm using spark 2.2.0 and the R `sparklyr` package as a front end. The worker nodes are spun up using an auto scaling group.
2. Created a directory to store temporary files in at `/tmp/jaytest`. There is one of these in each worker and one in the master.
3. Puttied into the spark master machine and the two workers, navigated to `home/ubuntu/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/spark-env.sh`, and modified the file to contain this line: `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS="/tmp/jaytest"`

Permissions for each of the `spark-env.sh` files are `-rwxr-xr-x`, and for the jaytest folders are `drwxrwxr-x`.

As far as I can tell this is in line with all the advice I've read online. However, when I load some data into the cluster it still ends up in `/tmp`, rather than `/tmp/jaytest`.

I have also tried setting the `spark.local.dir` parameter to the same directory, but also no luck.

Can someone please advise on what I might be missing here?

Edit: I'm running this as a standalone cluster (as the answer below indicates that the correct parameter to set depends on the cluster type).

Comment: You restarted Spark service after making the changes?

Comment: Yes, restarted the service.

Answer (score 1):

As per the spark documentation it is clearly saying that if you have configured Yarn Cluster manager then it will be overwrite the spark-env.sh setting. Can you just check in Yarn-env or yarn-site file for the local dir folder setting.

"this will be overridden by SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS (Standalone, Mesos) or LOCAL_DIRS (YARN) environment variables set by the cluster manager."
source - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/configuration.html

Comment: Thanks Vijay. I'm running a standalone cluster, so as per the documentation I'm trying to set the `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` parameter rather than the `spark.local.dir` parameter (since the former will overwrite the latter).

Answer (score 1):

Mac env, spark-2.1.0, and spark-env.sh contains:

```
export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/Users/kylin/Desktop/spark-tmp
```

Using spark-shell, it works.

Did you use the right format?

Comment: Thanks kylin, tried adding `export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/path/to/dir` to the conf file but didn't work using sparklyr (I'm not using the shell - need a solution that works via sparklyr). What do you mean by 'using the right format'?